# Sqlite3 under development group but still getting Heroku deployment Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, sqlite

This is my gem file

```
  source 'https://rubygems.org'

  gem 'rails', '4.2.2'
  gem 'sass-rails', '5.0.2'
  gem 'uglifier', '2.5.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '4.1.0'
  gem 'jquery-rails', '4.0.3'
  gem 'turbolinks', '2.3.0'
  gem 'jbuilder', '2.2.3'
  gem 'sdoc', '0.4.0', group: :doc

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
  gem 'byebug', '3.4.0'
  gem 'web-console', '2.0.0.beta3'
  gem 'spring', '1.1.3'
end

group :production do
gem 'pg'
gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

Wants to use Sqlite for development and PostgreSQL for production and I know Heroku does not support sqlite but. Even after I move sqllite under development test still getting same database related error.

When I totaly delete sqllite3 my code works fine. I know I am missing something but any idea about what it is.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Make Sure you use $ bundle install --without production and then $ bundle update. if doesn't work, include more information to your question along with error message.

Comment: also can you share yr deployment callback error

Comment: Have you tried 'bundle install' after changing gem file.

Comment: please share your database.yml and update the bundle...please delete gem.lock file and install bundle again..may this help you.

Comment: Tried the $bundle install --without production and bundle update it does not work. Console says production gems are not installed when I run bundle update but other than that same error now trying to delete gemlock file

Comment: Also try to use bundle install --without development test just to test is this a configuration related error.
Below you can find my database.yml file @NitinKumar
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3
production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3

Comment: @PadmanabanGokula yes bundle install --without production and bundle update I did those. So this configuration is just fine then?

Comment: @NitinKumar your comment about database.yml helped. Reconstruct that file and it is working right now. Thanks a lot. Finally solve it. If you wish you can move it to the answers dont know how to choose a comment as answer.

Comment: I strongly recommend using the same database in development as you do in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update the bundle by

```
bundle update
```

So this will update you gem list

OR

delete `Gemfile.lock` file and run

```
bundle install
```

which will create a new `Gemfile.lock` with the new updated gems (in your case removing `sqlite` gem and adding `pg` gem).

Hope this helps.